DDD: big immutable item with some references to entity identifiers, should it be value object or entity?
Let's say I have a Mail, this mail have many properties given by the constructor (for example, 10-15 parameters).
This mail can't be edited (immutable), the user has specifically requested to send this content. Mail has no methods but multiple constructors (for managing different scenarios), and it has few references on other entity identifiers (for example a reference on the identifier of the sender and the receiver).
Is it okay to make Mail a value object or should it be an entity ?
Some of the issues raised :
Mail have some references on other entity identifiers. Some developpers says a value object can have a reference on an identifier while others says only entities can have references on entity identifiers. Both sides seems to have good points.
Mail doesn't need an identifier. it will not be modified. However, the item will have to be stored in a database to be logged.
A Mail is a Mail. If we have items with same sent date, same mail subject and mail body, with same sender and receiver, in principle it is the same mail.
If Mail is considered value object, we still have the problem that it have several constructors with many parameters (smell code), we will probably need to use builder pattern to construct this object value.
If Mail is considered entity, we will have an anemic domain model. We could more or less add methods to fill the properties and at the same time remove the big constructors, but Mail will no longer be an immutable element.
I've encountered this kind of scenario several times without knowing what to do. There are obviously some subtleties specific to each case, but similar questions/issues come up.
What would be the best approach ?

Every mail message has a Message-ID: header, of the format localpart@globalpart, essentially GUID@domain.name. It's used for things like loop detection, and would be perfect for your PK. A MUA might choose not to generate one. The first MTA that sees it missing will generate that header for you. You should generate it when you create a Mail message, so you can conveniently name the message.


A Mail is a Mail. If we have items with same sent date, same mail
subject and mail body, with same sender and receiver, in principle it
is the same mail.

Have you never sent the same mail to a list of people? Do they all get the same mail, or a copy?
It doesn't make sense intuitively for Mail to be a value object. Classic examples are Date, Money, Address etc
If we are trying to work out the deciding factor I think having to include the time of sending is a key smell.
If you have an unsent mail and then send it, are those two different mails?
Then consider the practical side. What's the primary key for mails in your database? A composite key consisting of all the fields is going to be big and difficult to use, If an email changes state, is resent, edited etc it's going to be super useful to be able to modify its properties rather than treat it as an immutable object.
Also, what's the issue in Mail being an entity? ADM isn't bad, and if you don't like it you can just stick methods for Mail.Send() etc on the object.
What's the benefit in making it an immutable value object? Do you have some clever bulk mailing system where things are easier if you can never edit an email?
The best approach is to give it a GUID ID, use that as the pk on your database, and make an object called MailSender that sends Mails.

I've tried to write this question so that it's generic enough to be relevant and useful to everyone.
My current project involves mail templates and customisation. The mail at the end of the chain is ultimately just the final rendering that is sent to the receiver (hence the use of immutability).
I hadn't thought of it that way. Thank you for this answer. Just a question about the GUID ID, Is there a specific reason for using GUID, rather than a big int ?

you should always use GUIDs esp in this case where you will want to generate Mails before saving them

I think you are conflating some things here.
An object like Mail can be an entity (with some ID as primary key), still one could make it immutable, there is no need to implement it as a value object. One difference between entities and value objects is that value objects must not be mutable, but entities may be mutable, but the latter isn't mandatory.
When Mail has (currently) no methods, that makes it an Anemic Domain Object, regardless whether it is modeled as an entity or as a value object. We don't know why your Mail objects don't have any methods in your system and if it would make sense to give them some, because we don't know anything about the use case in your system and the potential behavioural implementation. But whatever is the reason, it should not depend on Mail being an entity or value object.

I didn't know about this fact on immutable and DDD. Thank you for your answer. About the Anemic domain class, as I understand it is an anti-pattern, I mentioned anemic domain model on the question, because while it is okay than value object is an anemic domain class, for entity it is not. Is this correct ?

@VianneyDoleans: An anemic domain model is an "anti-pattern" only when there are certain operations in your system which could be easily placed inside certain domain objects, but one misses that occasion. This holds for value objects as well as for entities. Note also sometimes you can have a "Rich Domain Model" and still some single anemic objects. So tell us -why does Mail have no methods in your system? Aren't there any?  Or are there technical restrictions which forbids to place certain operations there?

... Note also the term "anti-pattern" is often just an indicator for a heuristic, do yourself a favor and don't become dogmatic about it. There are a lot of contexts where an anemic domain model can be a perfect valid solution. But your question does not provide enough information to let us assess whether your case falls into that category or not.

Definitions
The difference between an entity and a value object is that:

an entity has a unique identity: it is not important if this identity materilizes in one id field (mail-id) or in a combination of several fields (e.g. "our mail from this data/time to  receiver Xyz").
a value object has no identity: only the combination of its value components matter.

The fact that some value components of the object are references to other objects do not change this matter.
Consequence
If the mail is immutable you have the choice to deal with it technically as an entity or a value object.
However, if in the reality of your domain the mail has an identity or one use to refer to specific mails, it should be considered as an entity for semantic reasons. (personally I'd recommend this latter option for mails)
Special remark
The official DDD definition of value object given by Evans is:

An object that describes some characteristic or attribute but carries no concept of identity.

This concept is language independent.
Immutability and value are two orthogonal concepts that are dealt with differently depending on implementation language semantics that can make them overlap or not.
In Java for example, all objects are by reference. So value objects requires immutability.
In C++, objects have by default a value semantic. An object can embed value objects that are not immutable (not const in C++ speak). You can change the value components of such a value object e.g. the day of a date and just have a different value. The consistency of the value model is achieved by comparing objects by value. (I do not mention pointers and references that allow to give identity even to value objects, to avoid creating confusion for simple ddd concepts with complex implementation language features)
